# Minkowski's upper bound

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Show that every ideal class of K contains an integral ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ such that

$N\mathfrak{b}\leq \frac{n!}{n^n}(\frac{4}{\pi})^s\sqrt{|d_K|}$

I couldn't find a proper proof of the statement. I can prove that every non-zero integral idea $\mathfrak{a}$ in K contains non-zero element $\alpha$ such that

$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)\leq \frac{n!}{n^n}(\frac{4}{\pi})^s\sqrt{|d_K|}N\mathfrak{a}$.

But was not able to proceed from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: given $\mathfrak b$, take an integral ideal $\mathfrak a$ such that $\mathfrak a \mathfrak b$ is principal.

Comment: Thanks!!Can you suggest a good book for Minkowski's theorems and Algebraic Number Theory.Our professor chose Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory and honestly it is hard to get through(given I haven't done Galois theory)

Comment: Galois theory is important, and I think generally considered more elementary than algebraic numbers. But I happen to know one book that does not use Galois theory explicitly: Hecke's *Lectures on the theory of algebraic numbers* (translated from German). It uses normal fields and conjugates, presented in an elementary way, but not the heavy parts of Galois theory.